# Using OpenStreetMap data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I have QGIS 3.4.14-Madeira installed. I'm trying to access OpenStreetMap using QGIS.

The instructions at [Using OSM Data in QGIS](https://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/osm-in-qgis/) go to `Vector → OpenStreetMap` but this is not in the drop list that appears under Vector.

Instead I see:

```
Geoprocessing Tools  
Geometry Tools  
Analysis Tools  
Data Management Tools  
Research Tools
```

How do I access OSM data from QGIS?

Comment: This might fit better on [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) but first off, you need to define what kind of data you're looking for. There are a ton of sources for US vector data, straight from the governmental agencies. Also, you should bear in mind that QGIS and other data manipulation programs aren't meant to provide you with the data.

Comment: QGIS has several plugins that will allow you to either connect to OSM data in WMS format, or download OSM vector data to your computer. Open the plugin manager and search for "OSM" or "open street map" to find them. Each plugin works differently; some plugins add an option to a menu, others add a new button to an existing toolbar, others add a new toolbar. Once the plugin is installed you have to figure out where its controls are to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions that you are following from that link to [Using OSM Data in QGIS](https://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/osm-in-qgis/) say near their beginning:

> We assume that you’ve already downloaded and installed QGIS 2.x.

You are using a version of QGIS 3.x, and so I think you should look for documentation written for QGIS 3.x instead.